Is the phrase "heaven and earth" an idiom?

Was the phrase "heaven and earth" an idiom in Matthew 5:17-18; Matthew 24:35; Mark 13:31; Luke 16:17; 21:33; 2 Peter 3: 7, 10, 13?

Was the tabernacle referenced as heaven and earth?



This answer focusses on the meaning of the expression heaven and earth. It provides a slightly different perspective to the thoughtful answer by Dottard.
The primary meaning of heaven and earth is "creation as a whole." It is an example of a literary device known as a merism. This is where the totality of something is described by its extreme points. Consider these examples:

I searched high and low for my lost phone. ( = I searched everywhere for the phone.)


From marriage vows: for richer, for poorer; in sickness and in health. ( = in all circumstances of life.)

So when in Genesis we read this:

Genesis 1:1 NIV
In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.

We should understand that, to use a modern term, God has created the whole universe.
This meaning makes sense of all the examples listed in the OP and in Dottard's reply. Consider for example Matthew 24:35.

Matthew 24.35 NIV
Heaven and earth will pass away, but my words will never pass away.

Dottard's explanation of this verse is that heaven and earth is not comprehensive, because it is distinguished from my words, the words of Jesus. But the better understanding is that heaven and earth is comprehensive within its own framework. It's just that Jesus' words are outside that framework. In the same way, "the heavens and the earth" in Genesis 1 embrace all of creation, but they do not include God, because God is not part of creation. Jesus is saying that his words are eternal; even if the whole universe came to an end, his words would remain.
Revelation 5:13 is an interesting variation on this theme. John writes:

Revelation 5:11-13 NIV
11 Then I looked and heard the voice of many angels, numbering thousands upon thousands, and ten thousand times ten thousand. They encircled the throne and the living creatures and the elders. 12 In a loud voice they were saying:
“Worthy is the Lamb, who was slain,
to receive power and wealth and wisdom and strength
and honor and glory and praise!”
13 Then I heard every creature in heaven and on earth and under the earth and on the sea, and all that is in them, saying:
“To him who sits on the throne and to the Lamb
be praise and honor and glory and power,
for ever and ever!”

John here is overwhelmed by this extraordinary vision of heaven. He describes the whole of creation worshipping God, and he does it by referring to "the heavens and the earth and under the earth and in the sea and all in them."
Now technically we could think of this as heaven and earth being one part of creation, and under the earth being another part of creation. But this is arbitrary and misses the big literary picture. We would make the same mistake if we took the power and wealth and wisdom and strength and honor and glory and praise due to Jesus and tried to assign those words to seven different areas of authority. We should group them together as a comprehensive expression of Jesus' authority in all its rich totality. We should imagine John emptying his thesaurus in a futile effort to find a set of words to describe the indescribable.
It's the same with heaven and earth in verse 13. It's not a separate part of a larger entity; it's part of a string of words that is only intended to be read as a single and integrated reality: creation as a whole.

Excellent response, I agree given the term universe does not exist in the ancient Hebrew language they would have used heavens and earth to essentially mean everything that is created, what we would refer to as universe today. And in Biblical cosmology we also have types and  representations, the heavens and the earth were a type of temple, that Eden represented also on a smaller scale that then the tabernacle represented on an even smaller scale, so while you didn’t address the OP’s second point yes the heavens and the earth were representative of the tabernacle.

Question 1 - "Heaven and Earth"
The short answer is that the phrase "heaven and earth" MOSTLY refers to our entire world (but not always).
"Heaven and earth" refer to our whole world:

Matt 11:25 - At that time Jesus declared, “I praise You, Father, Lord of the heaven and the earth, because You have hidden these things from the wise and learned, and revealed them to little children.
Matt 28:18 - And having come to them, Jesus spoke to them, saying, "All authority in heaven and on the earth has been given to Me.

Places where "heaven and earth" does not mean the entire world:

Matt 5:18 - For I tell you truly, until heaven and earth pass away, not a single jot, not a stroke of a pen, will disappear from the Law until everything is accomplished. [NOTE: this again only refers to the sinful things and excludes the righteous in the judgement of Rev 21:1.]  The same is true in Luke 16:17.
2 Peter 3:7 - But by the same word now the heavens and the earth exist, having been stored up for fire, being kept unto the day of judgment and destruction of ungodly men. [NOTE: this does NOT include the righteous and thus is NOT universal.]
Matt 24:35 - The heaven and the earth will pass away, but My words shall not pass away. [Again, this does not include everything - the Word of God is excluded.]  The same is true for Mark 13:31, Luke 21:33.

Places where "heaven and earth" must be supplemented to include all things:

Phil 2:10 - that at the name of Jesus every knee should bow, in the heavens and on earth and under the earth,
Col 1:16 - because in Him were created all things in the heavens and upon the earth, the visible and the invisible, whether thrones or lordships or rulers or authorities; all things have been created through Him and unto Him.
Rev 5:13 - And I heard every creature in heaven and on earth and under the earth and in the sea, and all that is in them, saying: “To Him who sits on the throne and to the Lamb be praise and honor and glory and power forever and ever!”

**Question #2 - "Is the Tabernacle referenced as heaven and earth?"
I could find no evidence to support this assertion.  However there is much evidence that the heavenly temple is the location of the God's throne of authority: Ps 11:4, Isa 6:1, Jer 17:12, Eze 43:7, Zech 6:13, Rev 7:15, 16:17, etc.
